# Svelte prevent user input on mapbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, mapbox-gl-js

I am attempting to block user input when `cssDisableUserInput` is `true`.

So basically within my main tags I have this:

```html
<div id=userinput disabled={cssDisableUserinput}>
    <div id="map">
</div>
```

within my CSS I have:

```html
<style>
  #map {
    width: 1300px;
    height: 800px;  
  }
  #userinput{
    width: 1300px;
    height: 800px; 
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
```

And yet it completely blocks user input even when `cssDisableUserinput` is `false`.

What is a better approach to blocking user input?

Comment: `disabled` is only valid for certain elements relating to forms ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled)), `div` is not among those.

Comment: What do you mean by user input? You might want to disable mapbox interaction handlers, as shown in [this page](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-interaction-handlers/).

Answer (score 0):

The thing that prevents interaction is `pointer-events: none;`, not `disabled`. You cannot disable a `div`. You might want to extract that property into a separate class and apply that conditionally using your `cssDisableUserinput` flag.

```html
<div class:disable-events={cssDisableUserinput}>...</div>

<style>
  .disable-events { pointer-events: none; }
</style>
```

(I do not know the Mapbox API, maybe there is a built-in mechanism that would be better suited for achieving this. The above approach may still allow interaction via the keyboard.)